# Does the sum $\sum_n\cos\!\left(\frac{n\pi}{7}\right)^n$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether 
$$\sum_n\cos\!\left(\frac{n\pi}{7}\right)^n$$
either converges or diverges, using $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please consider including in your questions your own work. This way people would address easily your doubts and you would be more likely to get meaningful answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It diverges, because its general term does not tend to $0$: if $n=14k$, $a_n=1$.

Comment: And if $n = 7k$ $a_n = -1$ only if $7k$ is odd - so only half of the time.